# What do we mean visually by complex eigen values of a matrix? Intuition behind the rotation of space using a 2x2 matrix and eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

The rotation matrix on $\Bbb R^2$ , the Euclidean plane given by $$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ has two imaginary eigen values $i$ and $-i$. The definition of eigen vectors are those vectors $x$ that are parallel to $x$  [i.e. $Ax= \lambda x$].

Here the definition says $Ax=ix$ or $Ax=-ix$, since multiplying by $ i $ rotates my space by ninety degrees , does that essentially mean that we see two vectors in complex planes that are perpendicular to each other as being parallel to each other at the same time. What intuition am I missing here?

Comment: They are perpendicular according to a real inner product, but parallel according to a complex inner product. Are you actually missing anything? I'm not so sure you are.

Comment: @runway44 The eigenvectors are perpendicular in the hermitian product; not sure what "real inner product" means here

Comment: @PeterFranek The vectors $x$ and $ix$ are not perpendicular in a complex inner product $\langle-,-\rangle$, though they are perpendicular in the induced real inner product ${\rm Re}\langle-,-\rangle$.

Comment: @runway44 Eigenvectors are not $x$ and $ix$ but in this case $(1,i)$ and $(1,-i)$. Note that $x$ and $ix$ are just multiples. Real inner product is not a product on complex numbers at all.

Comment: @PeterFranek True but irrelevant. Both OP and I said "the vectors" not "the eigenvectors." I don't know what you mean by "not a product on complex numbers."

Comment: Relevant idea by N.Wildberger: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoTeTHSQSMU).

Comment: It's very easy to see what we mean visually – provided you can see in four dimensions. If you can't do that, well, that's why they invented algebra, to solve problems they couldn't solve by geometry.

Answer (score 1):

We have an intuition of what "parallel" means in a real inner product space. Algebraically, it means one vector is a scalar multiple of another vector. This can get tricky, though, if our scalars are complex.

A big reason this gets tricky is because not only can there be a complex inner product $\langle u,v\rangle$ (which gives complex values), but there is an induced real inner product $\mathrm{Re}\langle u,v\rangle$. For instance, the standard complex inner product space $\mathbb{C}^n$ may be reinterpreted as the real inner product space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. So for instance, this means that within $\mathbb{C}^1$ itself, any two complex numbers are "parallel" because they are all multiples of each other, but interpreted as a real inner product space this is no longer true - e.g. $1$ and $i$ are perpendicular, not parallel.

When you say the matrix $A$ rotates a vector by $90^{\circ}$ and is thus perpendicular, you are describing that from the point of view of the *real* inner product on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (or, of course, the real inner product subspace $\mathbb{R}^2$), but it is no longer true if we treat $\mathbb{C}^2$ as a *complex* inner product space, as an eigenvector $x$ and $Ax=ix$ are now "parallel" in the sense that algebraically they are scalar multiples of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to think to "i" not as a number, but rather as a funcion.

In complex plane, the multiplication by $i$ is a rotation of 90 degrees. In $\mathbb C^2$, the multiplication by $i$ acts as a rotation on each cohordinate. So we can identify the multiplication by $i$ with a function $R_i:\mathbb C^2\to \mathbb C^2$.

Your matrix $A$ acts on $\mathbb R^2$ which you can think sitting inside $\mathbb C^2$. And in fact $A$ acts on $\mathbb C^2$. So you may ask if the matrix $A$ and the multiplication by $i$ act in the same way on some vector of $\mathbb C^2$. In other words, you may ask if there is $X\in\mathbb C^2$ so that $AX=R_i(X)$. A complex eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $i$, is then a vector $X\in\mathbb C^2$ so that $AX$ gives the same result that the multiplication by $i$.
The equation $AX=iX$ now reads as $AX=R_i(X)$.

Note that if you identify $\mathbb C^2$ with $\mathbb R^4$, then the matrix $A$ becomes $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and the function $R_i$ is given by the multiplication by the matrix $R=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$

So in $\mathbb C^2=\mathbb R^4$ the problem of searching for eigenvectors with eigenvalue $i$ reduce to solve $AX=RX$ which is equivalent to search eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ of $R^{-1}A$. That is to say $X$ so that $R^{-1}AX=X$.